# VB.Net | Is there a way to reference a dynamic amount of variables as arguments to function/sub?

Tags: vb.net, variables, dynamic, reference, arguments

I'm trying to pass a dynamic amount of variables to a Sub by using ByRef;

Essentially I'm trying to create a module that I can easily import into my projects and make handling the file saving/loading process automated.

The Sub/Function would take a number of variables as references and then loop through them changing each one's value.

I realize I'm missing a crucial point in how visual basic's syntax works but I haven't been able to figure out what I need to do.

The code I've written for this is:

```
    Public Sub LoadSaveToVars(ByRef KeyNamesAndVars() As Object, ByVal FileLoc As String = "")
        If isEven(KeyNamesAndVars.Length) Then
            Dim Contents As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(FileLoc)
            Dim isOnName As Boolean = True
            Dim CurrentVal As String = ""
            For i = 0 To KeyNamesAndVars.Length - 1
                If isOnName Then
                    CurrentVal = GetStringValue(KeyNamesAndVars(i), Contents) 'Get the value of the key with the key name in the array
                    isOnName = False
                Else
                    KeyNamesAndVars(i) = CurrentVal 'Set the variable referenced in the array to the value
                    isOnName = True
                End If
            Next
        Else
            Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The key names and variables supplied are not even.", "Error loading to variables!")
        End If
    End Sub
```

And here's how I try to use this function:

```
Dim TestVar1 As String = ""
Dim TestVar2 As String = ""
LoadSaveToVars({"key1", TestVar1, "key2", TestVar2})
```

To keep this question clean I did not include the other functions, but I did make a poor attempt at drawing what I want to happen: https://gyazo.com/eee34b8dff766401f73772bb0fef981a
In the end, I want TestVar1 to be equal to "val1" and TestVar2 to be equal to "val2" and to be able to extend this to a dynamic number of variables. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you not pass a List(Of ...) ?

Comment: If it's a key\value type of argument, your best bet would be to use a Dictionary. The user of your method would need to pass a dictionary.

Comment: If you had a class with all the variables which need to be saved as properties then you could serialize that to, say, JSON with [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

Comment: Probably not a good fit for key/value pairs, but ParamArray does allow for a variable number of arguments.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/parameter-arrays

Comment: The old-school way of doing this would be with the ParamArray keyword. That would let you put any number of variables in the call to the method. The method would receive those values as an array. However, they have to be called with the ByVal modifier, which you said you require ByRef.

Comment: Give me a clue. What is this data being passed to your Sub and what does it have to do with Loading/Saving files? What does `GetStringValue` do with Contents?